# Changing Auto Layout Constraint in viewForHeaderInSection

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout

I have a custom section header and have created an outlet from the XIB file for an Auto Layout constraint, so that I can change the constraint's value dynamically. This works great after the view is loaded. But I'm having trouble getting the view to display correctly upon initial load. For some reason, my calls to set the constraint's constant value in viewForHeaderInSection aren't being honored. This makes it to where the view shows exactly like it's set up in the XIB file, rather than the dynamically variable way i want it to be. Here's my code in relevant part (Swift). The line that isn't working properly is header.spaceAboveBottomView.constant = 0. Please help!

```
class GroupHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
    ....
    @IBOutlet weak var bottomView: DropDownTabView!
    @IBOutlet weak var spaceAboveBottomView: NSLayoutConstraint!
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    var  header = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("GroupHeaderView", owner: self, options: nil).first as! GroupHeaderView

    header.bottomView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

    if (condition) {
        header.spaceAboveBottomView.constant = 48
    }
    else {
        header.spaceAboveBottomView.constant = 0   // NOT WORKING PROPERLY - XIB FILE HAS THIS CONSTRAINT AS 48, AND THIS CALL TO SET IT TO 0 ISN'T WORKING
    }

    header.bottomView.setNeedsDisplay()    // I'm sure I don't need all of these calls, but I have them just in case
    header.bottomView.layoutIfNeeded()
    header.layoutIfNeeded()
    header.setNeedsLayout()
    header.bottomView.setNeedsLayout()

    return header
}
```

Comment: `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` should be in an object that implements  `UITableViewDataSource`, most of the time it is your view controller

Comment: Yes, it is. For convenience and since it isn't relevant to the question, I just left that out. I have the custom header working quite nicely for various labels, text fields, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use that code to set default paddings.

```
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) { tableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding = 0 }
```